# How to Get Device name in Flutter Application?

Tags: flutter

I have to get Android Device Name,

I got the IOS Device Data as Below.

```
DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfo = await AppUtils.getDeviceDetails();
IosDeviceInfo iosInfo = await deviceInfo.iosInfo;
      deviceModel = iosInfo.model!;
      deviceName = iosInfo.name!;
      deviceOS = "IOS";
      osVersion = iosInfo.systemVersion!;
```

But How I can get Android Device Name?
Can I have to use any Other Package? because in this package i can not find any option to get android device name.

Answer (score 1):

Use Device Info Plus Plugin maintain by Flutter Community and here is the code

```
var release, sdkInt, modelAndroid, manufacturer;
var systemName, versionIOS, name, modelIOS;
PackageInfo packageInfo = await PackageInfo.fromPlatform();

                          if(Platform.isAndroid){
                            var androidInfo = await DeviceInfoPlugin().androidInfo;
                            release = androidInfo.version.release;
                            sdkInt = androidInfo.version.sdkInt;
                            manufacturer = androidInfo.manufacturer;
                            modelAndroid = androidInfo.model;
                          } else if(Platform.isIOS){
                            var iosInfo = await DeviceInfoPlugin().iosInfo;
                            systemName = iosInfo.utsname.sysname;
                            versionIOS = iosInfo.systemVersion;
                            name = iosInfo.name;
                          }

                          var details = Platform.isAndroid ? "Android Release & SDK : $release - $sdkInt "
                              +"\nAndroid Model : $manufacturer $modelAndroid" : "IOS System : $systemName"
                              +"\nIOS Version : $versionIOS" +"\nName : $name";
```

Here is the link : https://pub.dev/packages/device_info_plus

Answer (score 0):

You can use [device_info_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/device_info_plus) plugin to get the information for any platform.

This plugin supports null safety and is maintained by the flutter community.